# Page changes not displaying on my computer only

Tags: html, browser, browser-cache, browser-history

I have come across a strange issue with my company's site, and it seems to only affect my computer.  Changes that I have made to the raw HTML are not reflected in my browser (Firefox).

I have taken the following steps to resolving this issue, without any luck:

1. Ensured that the page was uploaded successfully to the correct directory (downloading the file from the server shows that it is the same file as the one just uploaded).
2. Cleared my browser history and cache, refreshed the page.
3. Opened the page in other browsers (IE, and Chrome).
4. RDP'd into our server and opened multiple browsers that way.

A colleague of mine sits directly across from me and he has opened the page in the same version of Firefox that I typically use and he can see the changes. He and I both work on the site regularly.

The strangest part is that I have made changes to this page before, and they showed on my screen instantly. These changes are still in place and visible, yet some HTML elements that existed before I made those changes do not show on my screen currently (despite still existing in the HTML).

Has anyone else ever experienced such a phenomenon? Is there anything else that I can try in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: *Opened the page in other browsers (IE, Chrome, and Firefox).* If these are other browsers, what browser are you having the problem in?

Comment: Maybe you connect through a proxy which caches some data.

Comment: @mickey Sorry, I was just listing all of the browsers that I checked in; Firefox is the one I usually use, IE and Chrome were the "other" browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing cache refresh? Try it by clicking Ctrl + F5